# How to use function from parent Vue component in child?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've got a problem. In parent component I get some data, calculate them and then return to props for child component. Now I call this function on button click, but I want to call it automatically for example every 1 sec. How can I do it?

Parent:

```
<template>
<Dialog :msg="message"/>
</template>
<script>
export default defineComponent({
  const message = ref({
      text: '',
  });
  return{

    checkStatus: (*some variables*) => {
        message.value.text = 'Loading...'
        return message;
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
  <h3>{{msg.text}}</h3>
</template>
<script>
export default defineComponent({
  props:['msg']
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timer to call the function as follows - for example to call `checkStatus` every 5 seconds, add:

```
setInterval(()=>{
   this.checkStatus()
},5000)
```

Comment: Where should I insert it?

Comment: Probably best place is in `mounted` or equivalent, assuming you want it to run as soon as the component is loaded.

Comment: In onMounted property this function is not defined: Cannot find name 'checkStatus', Property 'checkStatus' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: Are you defining `mounted` with arrow function? This can lead to an incorrectly scoped `this`.